# Ubuntu 18.04 black screen on reboot after upgrading to Linux Kernel 5.0?

Tags: upgrade, kernel, virtualbox, lubuntu

My Lubuntu 18.04 (as a VirtualBox 6.0.10 virtual machine) is just upgraded to

```
Linux pbox 5.0.0-23-generic #24~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Mon Jul 29 16:12:28 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

with an `apt upgrade`. After the upgrade, the VM shows a black screen with a cursor in the upper left corner, and seems to hang.

*Does anyone have similar experience with the new 5.0 Linux kernel, and know how to fix the problem?*

FYI, I can go to the GUI anytime after hitting `Ctrl+Alt+F1` and then `Ctrl+Alt+F7` without a problem. A `systemd-analyze blame` didn't show anything taking an excessive amount of time (3 seconds max) during reboot. But if I don't switch manually, the black green never disappears.

-- Update --

By the way, I got the new kernel via `apt-get` as follows:

```
sudo apt-get install --install-recommends linux-generic-hwe-18.04
```

Comment: 18.04 shouldn't have any higher than 4.15.0-55.60 . How did you get 5.0?

Comment: @wxl Please see my update

Comment: I installed the new kernel in an 18.04 VM running in VBox 6.0.10 on 18.04 and I don't experience the problem. I also made sure the VM was fully upgraded. Have any strange packages? Have you dug through the logs?

Comment: Do you have broadcom chipsets by chance?  esp. broadcom bluetooth?  *I could be wrong, if it's what I'm thinking it's a kernel module issue related to a broadcom module that you can resolve by blacklisting.  I forget specifics but I'd start by searching your `lshw` for anything BCM/broadcom; if you see none then my comment is worthless*

Comment: I also have problems with the 5.0.0-23 kernel that I got by simply updating with the GUI. The Ubuntu is installed on a real machine and it never starts. Starting it with the previous 4.18.0-25 kernel works.

Comment: Same problem, Ubuntu 18.04 doesn't load on 5.0 kernel which I received simply by apt-get full-upgrade'ing.

Answer (score 0):

I have got the similar issue. After reboot my VirtualBox machine. It won't boot to GUI but the terminal in "emergency mode". It just can't go into default mode. I have got 5.0.0.25 and 5.0.0.23, both doing the same thing.

I have got the problem solved. It appears that the attached USB devices (bluetooth and external HD) and their relevant settings are stopping the system booting to default mode. After detached them and disabled those settings, all good. Just re-attach and re-apply the settings, everything's up and running.

Comment: Hey, I have got the problem solved. It appears that the attached USB devices (bluetooth and external HD) and their relevant settings are stopping the system booting to default mode. After detached them and disabled those settings, all good. Just re-attach and re-apply the settings, everything's up and running.

Answer (score -1):

I, too, received the 5.0.0-23-generic kernel today, after doing my typical

sudo apt-get update

No black screen, however.  So far, everything seems to work.

Comment: I'm not sure that's a good answer to the OP's question, at least in that it doesn't solve their problem. I would suggest you move that to a comment rather than an answer.